# Is there a Master Password for Google Drive documents?

Tags: google-drive, security

So I have a special document that I already set to self-private. However, I want to also make a Master Password for that document in case somebody accidentally gets into my account or the somehow access it.

Does Google Drive have a feature that will allow me to set a Master Password for a specific document so that I cannot open it unless I enter the password correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [cannot](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/AAD6CnLqQFE) set a master password for a specific document. The best you can do is to encrypt your file before storing it in Google Drive. Also, see [keeping your account secure](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/46526?hl=en).

Comment: Ok thanks. I just set the Verification code with my phone number but I tend to use different wifis a lot on my laptop. So if I use my laptop on a public wifi vs my home wifi will google think that this is an "untrusted computer"?